# Nginx PHP Failing with Large File Uploads (Over 6 GB)

Tags: php, nginx, file-upload, amazon-s3, hhvm

I am having a very weird issue uploading larges files over 6GB. My process works like this:

1. Files are uploaded via Ajax to an php script.
2. The PHP upload script takes the $_FILE and copies it over in chunks, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564643/copy-large-files-over-2-gb-in-php) to a tmp location.
3. The location of the file is stored in the db
4. A cron script will upload the file to s3 at a later time, again using fopen functions and buffering to keep memory usage low

My PHP(HHVM) and NGINX configuration both have their configuration set to allow up to 16GB of file, my test file is only 8GB.

Here is the weird part, the ajax will **ALWAYS** time out. But the file is successfully uploaded, its gets copied to the tmp location, the location stored in the db, s3, etc. But the AJAX runs for an hour even **AFTER all the execution is finished(which takes 10-15 minutes)** and only ends when timing out.

What can be causing the server not send a response for only large files?

Also error logs on server side are empty.

Comment: You need to post the code if you want some help figuring out what might be wrong with it.

Comment: Do you make repeated use of session_write_close() and session_start() in your ajax upload script? This can cause issues.

Answer (score 71):

A large file upload is an expensive and error prone operation. Nginx and backend should have correct timeout configured to handle slow disk IO if occur. Theoretically it is straightforward to manage file upload using multipart/form-data encoding RFC 1867.

According to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) in a multipart/form-data body, the HTTP Content-Disposition general header is a header that can be used on the subpart of a multipart body to give information about the field it applies to. The subpart is delimited by the boundary defined in the Content-Type header. Used on the body itself, Content-Disposition has no effect.

Let's see what happens while file being uploaded:

1) client sends HTTP request with the file content to webserver

2) webserver accepts the request and initiates data transfer (or returns error 413 if the file size is exceed the limit)

3) webserver starts to populate buffers (depends on file and buffers size)

4) webserver sends file content via file/network socket to backend

5) backend authenticates initial request

6) backend reads the file and cuts headers (Content-Disposition, Content-Type)

7) backend dumps resulted file on to disk

8) any follow up procedures like database changes

[image: client_body_in_file_only off;]

During large files upload several problems occur:

- the HTTP body request dumps on to disk and passes to backend which process and copy the file
- not possible to authenticate request before HTTP request content is uploaded to server
- while upload large files backend rarely requires a file content itself immediately

Let's start with Nginx configured with new location **http://backend/upload** to receive large file upload, back-end interaction is minimised (Content-Legth: 0), file is being stored just to disk. Using buffers Nginx dumps the file to disk (a file stored to the temporary directory with random name, it can not be changed) followed by POST request to backend to location **http://backend/file** with the file name in **X-File-Name** header.

To keep extra information you may use headers with initial POST request. For instance, having **X-Original-File-Name** headers from initial requests help you to match file and store necessary mapping information to the database.

[image: client_body_in_file_only on;]

Let's see how make it happen:

1) configure Nginx to dump HTTP body content to a file and keep it stored **client_body_in_file_only on;**

2) create new backend endpoint http://backend/file to handle mapping between temp file name and header **X-File-Name**

4) instrument AJAX query with header **X-File-Name** Nginx will use to send post upload request with

Configuration:

```
location /upload {
  client_body_temp_path      /tmp/;
  client_body_in_file_only   on;
  client_body_buffer_size    1M;
  client_max_body_size       7G;

  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  proxy_set_header           X-File-Name $request_body_file; 
  proxy_set_body             off;
  proxy_redirect             off;
  proxy_pass                 http://backend/file;
}
```

> Nginx configuration option [client_body_in_file_only](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_in_file_only) is
>   incompatible with multi-part data upload, but you can use it with AJAX
>   i.e. XMLHttpRequest2 (binary data).

If you need to have back-end authentication, only way to handle is to use [auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html), for instance:

```
location = /upload {
  auth_request               /upload/authenticate;
  ...
}

location = /upload/authenticate {
  internal;
  proxy_set_body             off;
  proxy_pass                 http://backend;
}
```

[image: client_body_in_file_only on; auth_request on;]

Pre-upload authentication logic protects from unauthenticated requests regardless of the initial POST Content-Length size.

Comment: Brilliant! How would you configure this to operate without the proxy? Would it work to add the line  `return 201 $request_body_file;` instead?

Comment: @bcattle *proxy_pass* shouldn't be necessarily a backend upstream URL, it can be a named internal location, what do you try to achieve?

Comment: upload file in js: `const file = document.getElementById('file').files[0]; const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open('POST', '/upload', false); xhr.send(file);` html: `<input id="file" type="file" onchange="upload()" />` just a example, use asnyc in production

Comment: @bcattle and anyone else wondering about their question: it does not work if you `return` at the end of the `location` directive. I found it didn't work after a couple of hours of trying different config options. But, you can use nginx itself to be the proxy target. See https://spielwiese.fontein.de/2017/04/23/simple-file-uploading-in-nginx/ for an example of setting up a server to listen on port 4000 and setting the `proxy_pass` value to `127.0.0.1:4000`.

Comment: same code i using but error 405 showing in the web browser. can u help me.