# Request headers added on file uploaded via nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, postman

I've followed [Nginx PHP Failing with Large File Uploads (Over 6 GB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371643/nginx-php-failing-with-large-file-uploads-over-6-gb/44751210#44751210) to enable file upload in nginx.

Current nginx.conf:

```
     location /upload {
     root /tmp;
     client_body_temp_path          /tmp/foo/;
     client_body_in_file_only       on;
     client_body_buffer_size        128K;
     client_max_body_size           50M;

     proxy_pass_request_headers on;
     proxy_set_header           X-File-Name $request_body_file; 
     proxy_set_body             off;
        proxy_redirect             off;
        proxy_pass                 http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
    }
```

Files get uploaded, however request headers get applied at the beginning of the file, for example:

```
----------------------------306210650889621245841197^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foo.bar"^M
Content-Type: application/octet-stream^M
^M
...rest of the file...
```

I'm testing uploads using Postman, however I think request headers get applied when nginx processes the file. Is there a way to remove these headers?

Comment: Do you want to remove these headers? right?

Comment: @LovekeshKumar either remove them or not add them in the first place if that's possible.

Comment: What's the problem if headers go with file?

Comment: The program that uses the file later on can't use it because it's corrupted.